# unable to play video in html other than ogg format

Tags: html

I am unable to play video in mp4 or avi format. I am only able to play ogg format. This file is suppose to run locally.

[image]

code:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
<source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
    
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
<source src="motion_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

            
                
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
<source src="motion_1.avi" type="video/avi">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

i have check in IIS that mp4 and avi is enabled but i still cant get it to work. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Does the browser support those formats? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: i think so? i tried chrome,firefox, and ie. no errors on console